# Pandas Dataframe 2D selection with row number and column label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

What's the easiest way to get a value in a Pandas 2D Dataframe with the row number and the column title as indicers (a combo of loc and iloc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}, index=['i', 'j', 'k'])
df
   a  b
i  1  4
j  2  5
k  3  6
```

If you have an index that isn't numeric, and want to grab the first and second rows from column 'a', you can either use `loc` with indexing—

```
df.loc[df.index[[0, 1]], 'a']

i    1
j    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Or, `iloc` + `get_loc`—

```
df.iloc[[0, 1], df.columns.get_loc('a')]

i    1
j    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Perfect, I like the first one! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `loc` and pass it the row/index and column name:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]})

print(df.loc[0, 'b'])
```